# Zend Framework's "zf" CLI tool - why nothing from quickstart works?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am going through the Zend Framework "quickstart" tutorial at the mo'.

I have PHP and Zend <strike>Server</strike> Framework on my Ubuntu machine (all installed from Synaptic).

The following zf usage has worked.

> zf create project projectToCreate

But, after that, nothing works! For example:

> zf enable layouts (it moans "Action 'enable' is not a valid action.")
>
> zf configure db-adapter blahblah (it moans "Action 'configure' is not a valid action.")

SO, my question is, is this an error in the tutorial or is there something fishy with my installation of Zend Framework? If so, any hints are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: ooops, of course I mean "Zend Framework" and not "Zend Server"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you create the project try changing directory to projectToCreate.

```
cd projectToCreate
```

I think on linux

Then run your zf commands.

Comment: The next thing is to make sure zf finds the right zend framework version. Is it possible you have another one (in xampp for example) that could be interfering?

Comment: Er...only one zend framework on the system (AFAIK). Installed it v. recently. How do I ensure this anyway?

Comment: @Douglas check php.ini's include paths. Also what version of zf are you using? Its possible you have missmatching zf tool and library.

Answer (score 0):

It all happening due to XAMPP's version of Zend tool. Remove the Zend folder in php/PEAR/ and also overwrite files at php/ (where php.exe reside) from ZendFramework\bin*.